# Loader gif when component loads angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am using ng2-pdf-viewer to display a pdf. For now when pdf is loading blank page appears. I want to add a loader gif while pdf loads and hide it when loading is done. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try out this library https://github.com/viktorhajer/simple-pdf-viewer

Answer (score 1):

ng2-pdf-viewer provide an event [after-load-completed](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer#after-load-complete%20after-load-complete), that you can use to hide the gif. And, another event called [on-progress](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer#on-progress), that you can use to set up a boolean to `true`, then use it in a *ngIf, like this:

```
<pdf-viewer 
  [src]="pdfSrc" [render-text]="true" (on-progress)="showGif($event)">
</pdf-viewer>

<img src="loading.gif" *ngIf="loading"/>
```

in your component class, do this:

```
(...)
public loading = false;
(...)

showGif(event: {loaded: number, total: number}) {
 this.loading = event.loaded < event.total;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! It is working fine! but a little problem is that is it is calling showGif twice. While it is not calling hideGif at all. Due to which loader is not hiding after is is shown.

Comment: Hmm. Well, some kind of adjusts : D. I was thought that when _after-load-complete_ was finished, it would the last to set `loading` property - in this case, to false. Maybe, _on-progress_ run one more time, after _after-load-completed_ was triggered.

Comment: But  after-load-complete was never called. I confirmed it by console.log

Comment: Try to put $event as parameter of showGif. I will update this answer. Just a minute! : )

Comment: on-progress event provide an object with *loaded* and *total* properties. Maybe it is useful to know it all things was loaded, then set _loading_ to false.

Answer (score 0):

Put like loading=true. Form the method where you are trying to load the pdf

```
<pdf-viewer class="pdf-viewer" [src]="pdfSrc" (page-rendered)="pageRendered($event)" style="display: block;">
```

page-rendered method will be called after the pdf is loaded. So set loading=false in it.

```
pageRendered(e: CustomEvent) {
    this.loading = false;
    //console.log('(page-rendered)', e);
  }
```

ngx-loading component will help you to show the loading magic squares.

```
<ngx-loading [show]="loading" [config]="{fullScreenBackdrop: true}"></ngx-loading>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Use pace.js. No configuration required :)

Comment: Please do not post one-line answers which simply point to a library. At least explain how to use the library to answer the OP's question.